# Reshape array that is stored in a collection and export to CSV

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of Facebook Page Likes (titled **pagelikes**) that is stored in a Mongo database/JSON file. Below is an example of one entry.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4725bf8731b8faf4c04595bb"),
    "user_id" : "0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100",
    "page_likes" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "859302873383",
            "name" : "Hotdogs"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "8593683902",
            "name" : "Video Games"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "849204859849028",
            "name" : "Road Bikes"
        }
    ]
}
```

**id** = the unique Facebook Page identifier, **name** = the name of a Facebook page.

I would like to export this entire collection to a CSV file with three columns, **user_id**, **page_likes.id**, **page_likes.name**. It would look like the following:

```
user_id                     page_likes.id     page_likes.name
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100  859302873383      Hotdogs
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100  8593683902        Video Games
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100  849204859849028   Road Bikes
...                         ...               ...
```

The JSON file is quite large (4GB), contains over 120K users, and there is no limit on the number of an entry has.

I have tried and failed with mongoexport, although an aggregation framework seems most useful (possibly the project and unwind functions). That said, I have little experience with Mongo.

Any advice, examples or suggestions would be very helpful.

Many thanks,

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with this in a number of ways.

Firstly if you have MongoDB 3.4 available then you could use a ["View"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) in order to represent the collection with the array contents "un-wound". A "View" is basically an aggregation pipeline statement that appears to be a normal collection as far as most actions that would use a collection are concerned.

So presuming your source collection is called `"pages"` here, then you would create the "View" with:

```
db.createView("pageArray", "pages", [{ "$unwind": "$page_likes" }])
```

Then you can query the collection as normal:

```
db.pageArray.find()

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4725bf8731b8faf4c04595bb"),
    "user_id" : "0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100",
    "page_likes" : {
        "id" : "859302873383",
        "name" : "Hotdogs"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4725bf8731b8faf4c04595bb"),
    "user_id" : "0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100",
    "page_likes" : {
        "id" : "8593683902",
        "name" : "Video Games"
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4725bf8731b8faf4c04595bb"),
    "user_id" : "0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100",
    "page_likes" : {
        "id" : "849204859849028",
        "name" : "Road Bikes"
    }
}
```

And subsequently issue the `mongoexport` as if it were a normal collection:

```
mongoexport -d test -c pageArray --type=csv --fields user_id,page_likes.id,page_likes.name
2017-07-05T13:14:11.588+1000    connected to: localhost
user_id,page_likes.id,page_likes.name
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100,859302873383,Hotdogs
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100,8593683902,Video Games
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100,849204859849028,Road Bikes
2017-07-05T13:14:11.589+1000    exported 3 records
```

Of course adding [`--out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-out) or a standard redirect to actually output to a file.

If your MongoDB is an older version but at least has `$out` available ( from MongoDB 2.6 ) then write to another collection:

```
db.pages.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$page_likes" },
  { "$project": { "_id": 0 } },
  { "$out": "pagesArray" }
])
```

Then you basically run the same `mongoexport` as above since it's also a collection that is accessible to do so.

If you really don't want to create either a "View" or "another collection", then you could simply send a short script to the `mongo` shell. Albeit in a very hacky way:

```
mongo --quiet --eval '
    print("user_id,page_likes.id,page_likes.name");
    db.pages.aggregate([ 
      { "$unwind": "$page_likes" },
      { "$project": { "_id": 0 } },
    ]).forEach(p => print(`${p.user_id},${p.page_likes.id},${p.page_likes.name}`))'
```

Or even without `aggregate()` and `$unwind` at all:

```
mongo --quiet --eval '
    print("user_id,page_likes.id,page_likes.name");
    db.pages.find({},{ _id: 0 }).forEach(p =>
       p.page_likes.forEach(l => print(`${p.user_id},${l.id},${l.name}`)))'
```

Which gives you the same output:

```
user_id,page_likes.id,page_likes.name
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100,859302873383,Hotdogs
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100,8593683902,Video Games
0939bf9w9804842f9f817ad100,849204859849028,Road Bikes
```

Note also that if you want or "need" a different delimiter than comma `,`here, then either of the two last approaches with the shell is probably the way to go. As this is "scheduled" for addition to `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` with [TOOLS-87](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-87), but of course is "yet to be resolved". So if you want different output, then you do it yourself.